# display characteristics in TextView

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new in developing apps especially in BLE. I'm trying to display realtime data of three characteristics in TextViews from my BLE device which has a custom service with three characteristics. Only the first characteristics displays a value but the other two does not. Here is my onCharacteristicsChange under BluetoothGattCallback:

```
       public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            UUID characteristicUUID = characteristic.getUuid();
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();

            String value = new String(data);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (characteristicUUID.equals(UUID.fromString("082b9438-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"))) {
                        mDataTextView1.setText(value);
                    } else if (characteristicUUID.equals(UUID.fromString("082b9622-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"))) {
                        mDataTextView2.setText(value);
                    } else if (characteristicUUID.equals(UUID.fromString("082b976c-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"))) {
                        mDataTextView3.setText(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Here also my onServicesDiscovered under BluetoothGattCallback:

```
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic1 = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("082b91ae-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"))
                        .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("082b9438-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"));
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic2 = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("082b91ae-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"))
                        .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("082b9622-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"));
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic3 = gatt.getService(UUID.fromString("082b91ae-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"))
                        .getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("082b976c-e83c-11e8-9f32-f2801f1b9fd1"));

                if (characteristic1 != null && characteristic2 != null && characteristic3 != null) {
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic1, true);
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic2, true);
                    gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic3, true);

                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor1 = characteristic1.getDescriptor(
                            UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor2 = characteristic2.getDescriptor(
                            UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
                    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor3 = characteristic3.getDescriptor(
                            UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

                    if (descriptor1 != null && descriptor2 != null && descriptor3 != null) {
                        descriptor1.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                        descriptor2.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                        descriptor3.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

                        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor1);
                        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor2);
                        gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor3);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How to display the two characteristics or where in my code is wrong? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to writeDescriptor can not be submitted in sequence like that, since only one GATT operation is allowed at a time per BluetoothGatt object. Please wait for the onDescriptorWrite callback before writing the next one.